# Access data validation event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a few entry fields that have validation rules. Next to the fields I have check marks or x marks to show if the data is correct. I want to catch the data validation event so that I can change these marks. Is there anyway to get at the data validation event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access doesn't expose a validation event.  You could create a Before Update procedure to check whether the entry is valid, and drive the check marks from there.

But it may be better to use each control's After Update event.  At that point you can assume the value is valid.  Also consider what should happen with Nulls if they are allowed ... whether you would want the check mark for a Null value.